# QGIS 2.18.2 DB Manager on Mac OS no longer supports SpatiaLite

Tags: qgis, spatialite, mac

I recently updated QGIS from 2.18.1 to 2.18.2 on a Mac OS using the KyngChaos installer.

After the update, the DB Manager no longer recognizes the SpatiaLite extension on sqlite databases. The below image shows the installed libraries in QGIS.

[image: QGIS install specs]

Geometry layers appear fine in the QGIS Browser Panel. I can add these layers to the Map Canvas without problems. When I open the same database in DB Manager, I don't see the SpatiaLite, GEOS, or PROJ libraries in the "General Info" description for the database. If I try to view a spatial layer's table, I get the following error, "no such function: GeometryType."

Comment: Installed QGIS 2.18.2 from KyngChoas on a fresh Mac OS (10.10) and DB Manager doesn't recognize SpatiaLite databases. Am I missing something?

Comment: Update: multiple new installs on different macOS boxes leaves DB Manager inoperable with SpatiaLite databases.